# Elementary Angular syntax issue with error handler declaration in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs

While going through the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) and converting it to my purposes, I decided that I want to combine the 2 varieties of error handler method shown into one, because i like the function of both.

This is all in one service, and these are the 2 methods from the tutorial:

```
  private handleError1(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(`Backend error code ${error.status}`, 
        `body: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened');
  }
```

which is called like this, where `Group` is my class from the REST server:

```
  getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Group[]>(`${this.restUrl}/group`).pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`fetched groups`)),
        catchError(this.handleError1)
      );
  }
```

and then alternatively, there is:

```
  private handleError2<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(`${operation} failed!`, error);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
```

which is called like this:

```
  getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Group[]>(`${this.restUrl}/group`).pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`fetched groups`)),
        catchError(this.handleError2<Group[]>('getGroups', []))
      );
  }
```

So I naively put together my combination error handler:

```
private handleError<T>(error: HttpErrorResponse, 
                   operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
....
```

but I am having problems because I can't figure out how to parameterise it within `catchError()`. That `HttpErrorResponse` is obviously implied somehow when it's the only parameter, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a bit more time on this.

First, I ensured I had a recent version of TypeScript. My project is using 3.1.1.

This is my method:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(error => this.handleError<Product[]>(error, 'get', [] ))
    );
  }
```

This is my error handler:

```
  private handleError<T>(err: HttpErrorResponse, operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

I'm not getting any compilation errors with this code.

I even turned on strict mode in my tsconfig.json:

```
"strict": true,
```

And it still compiled without syntax errors.

I built a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-retrieve-deborahk

Let me know if you aren't seeing the same result.

Comment: I get a big dirty compilation error from IntelliJ saying `Error:(62, 13) TS2345: Argument of type '(error: any) => (error: any) => Observable<Group[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Group[]>) => ObservableInput<{}>'. Type '(error: any) => Observable<Group[]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'. Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '(error: any) => Observable<Group[]>' but required in type 'Iterable<{}>'.`

Comment: Hmmm. I tried it in my code before posting and it worked. Do you have strict type checking on? Or other code you are not showing above?

Comment: That's the defaults. Both the IntelliJ built-in compiler and the external node.js when I run `ng serve --open`

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you running? Is your code basically the same as mine?

Comment: 3.3.3. I just upgraded it from 3.2.4. But I narrowed the issue down to a weird syntax I had used in  my return statement for `handleError()`, and now it's happy! Thanks